# Auto set feature image in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for php script that set the feature image (of the post) from the video embed code. 
Untill now, I saw only plugins that support specific websites. I'm looking for code that allow auto set feature image from any video embed code from any website.
Is that possible ?

Comment: Do [this search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=youtube+featured+image+is%3Aquestion), then replace `youtube` for `oembed`. Lots of good code.

Comment: maybe first you need to figure outhow to make a thumbnail of a video. But probably you can do it for all the videos sites.

Answer (score 0):

A generic implementation is impossible, because there are so many different players and platforms around.

As an example, YouTube have an API that allows you to grab the same screenshot they use for their videos.  Vimeo also have an API that is similar, but not the same.  Then look at LiveLeak, who don't have a formal API at all, or any of the thousands of third-party video players that sites use.  Many even use their own video player (think BBC and other large news sites).

The best you could hope for is a plugin that implements all of the big video sites.

Comment: I understand but I'm looking for solution because I have a tube site and I can't cut-post every feature image for any post. So, if I'll put video embed player instead the feature image.. Then I'll see "feature image" of any post. And I need to think how to unable play video and hide the player bottoms. (???)